# How can i convert the results of a LINQ to Entities Query to a list<>

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, combobox, listbox

```
 var term = from s in DB.Terms
                       select new { s.Term_ID, s.TermName };

            comboboxTerm.DataSource = term;
            combobox.DisplayMember = "Term_Name";
            combobox.ValueMember = "Term_ID";
```

i want to convert the above query to a list<> such that i can set the list as the Datasource to comboboxTerm. That would enable me get access to comboboxTerm selectedValue in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
var term = (from s in DB.Terms
                   select new { s.Term_ID, s.TermName }).ToList();
```

This will actually resolve your query as well, as by default you're returning an `IQueryable`

**BUT** for the Data Source of the combobox, you're best off using a dictionary, like so:

```
var term = (from s in DB.Terms
                   select new { s.Term_ID, s.TermName })
           .ToDictionary(s => s.Term_ID, s => s.TermName);
```

Then add the following to your combobox:

```
SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
comboboxTerm.DataSource = term.ToList();
```

OR

```
term = term.ToList();
```